# findcontrol textbox text without declaring variable c#

Tags: c#, findcontrol

Is there a way to turn these two lines of code into a single line of

```
TextBox tempTextBox= grdvwEncroachmentsID.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtbxBillTo") as TextBox;
string billToTemp = tempTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: Hmm, a programmer that has not debugged a NullReferenceException often enough would ask this.  The result is not "better", it is not more diagnosable, not more readable, not more efficient.  And it is wrong, never use `as` when you meant to use a `(cast)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the Line Break!

Just kidding. I assume you mean single [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements).

Here you go:

```
string billToTemp = (grdvwEncroachmentsID.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtbxBillTo") as TextBox).Text;
```

Not sure why you would do this, though. It's ugly.

Comment: What do you mean by ugly? The length of the line of code?

Comment: Yes. It makes it harder to read. And it gives you less room to declare your intentions. Also, if you ever want to re-use that TextBox variable, you will either have to declare a new one or put it into a variable (like you have in your question).

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was thinking.

Comment: +1 for sense of humour. The Elvis operator ?. can be used to avoid NullReference nasties. Fluent alignment can assist with readability.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses:

```
string billToTemp = (grdvwEncroachmentsID.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtbxBillTo") as TextBox).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string billToTemp = (grdvwEncroachmentsID.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtbxBillTo") as TextBox).Text;
```